# How do I disable update manager from installing gwibber?

Tags: update-manager, gwibber

I don’t use gwibber. Thus I don't want it. Thus I un-installed it.

However update manger still wants to install it again for me. How do I make it not.

That is, how do I add certain packages to a blacklist, so that they are not considered for installation?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is probably happening because an associated package is still around.

First, please try removing gwibber and associated packages from the terminal with:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove gwibber*
```

Then run:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

And see if Update Manager still wants to install it -- it *shouldn't.*

Comment: Additionally to izx's answer you might have to remove the `ubuntu-desktop` package. That's a meta-package depending on all the default ubuntu applications. If gwibber still wants to reinstall after you have purged it, try removing `ubuntu-desktop`.